# How to stop vim from indenting open parenthesis

Tags: vim

I got `set autoindent` because I want my indentation preserved, however the option does something else that I find extremely annoying, it indents text if i create a new line after opening a parenthesis. Like this:

```
(define (function)
  then it idents where this line starts, with 2 spaces
```

How do I preserve autoindenting actual indentation and not this 'smart' thing it's doing? (`smartindent` is off already)

I want whitespace indents to be copied down into new lines, I don't want anything else (such as inserting indents when i haven't inserted any).

Comment: Why do you think it's `autoindent` doing it?

Comment: `:set noai` it will not do anything. But you need to do indenting yourself which will be more annoying. What is actual indenting that you want?

Comment: I want whitespace indents to be copied down into new lines, I don't want anything else (such as inserting indents when i haven't inserted any). I think it's `autoindent` because turning it off removes the behavior (but it also removes the auto indentation that I want)

Comment: Wanna bet `lisp` is on? See `:help 'lisp`.

Comment: @melpomene THANK YOU, I didn't know there was language-specific settings, `:set nolisp` did the trick. It's weird that `:help lisp` shows `default off` when it wasn't off.

Comment: It is off by default. Do you have filetype plugins on? I'd expect the Lisp ftplugin to `set lisp`.

Comment: oh yeah I do, I believe I set it on because it was necessary for the syntax highlighting

Answer (score 4):

`autoindent` is very un-intelligent in general. It simply copies the previous line's indent without regard to the syntax.

If you have `filetype plugin indent on`, which is a common thing to find in vim configs, then you will load the lisp syntax when opening lisp files. The filetype plugin for lisp contains:

```
setl lisp
```

As noted in comments, the `lisp` setting will influence indentation. Other plugins might influence indentation, especially if parentheses are involved.

This minimal .vimrc file does what you are after. This may not work for you as-is because perhaps other things in your .vimrc, or in your plugins, will affect behavior as well, but this worked in my test.

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent
set nosmartindent
autocmd FileType lisp setlocal nolisp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also with `set nocindent`. It worked for me.